# mod_rewrite existing directories to index.php adds query string but works right for non-existing

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

So my directory structure is like this:

```
vhostrootdir/
|- app/
|- public/
   |- css/
   |- img/
   |- js/
```

This is my rewrite:

```
ServerName vhostname
<Directory  "vhost/root/dir">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require local

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1 -f
    RewriteRule ^((?s).*)$ public/$1 [END]
    RewriteRule ^((?s).*)$ index.php?_url=$1 [END]
</Directory>
```

If I go to `vhostname/whatever` then my php `$_GET["_url"]` returns `whatever` and the address bar stays `vhostname/whatever`, as desired.

However if I go to `vhostname/public` then `$_GET["_url"]` is `public/`. Notice the extra '/', although that doesn't bother me. **The issue is that the browser address bar also changes to** `vhostname/public/?_url=/public` **which I definitely don't want.**

To add to the confusion, if I go to `vhostname/public/` (notice the additional '/'), then it works correctly. I get `$_GET["_url"]` is `public/` and the address bar doesn't change.

The situation is the same if I go to `vhostname/app`.

**Edit:** <strike>Turns out it was a browser history issue. I cleared Chrome's history and that fixed it.</strike> Nevermind that didn't fix it. After changing the DocumentRoot to the public folder it was still happening on the public and app urls, but then clearing the history it stopped happening on them and is happening on the public folder subfolders now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I believe I have figured out the issue. Because the URL before rewriting was resolving to a directory and because I was omitting the trailing `/`, apache was automatically sending a 301 Moved Permanently redirect with the trailing `/` added on. I guess due to the order apache does things, the redirect was also picking up the rewrite and instead of 301 redirecting from `http://<vhostname>/img` to `<vhostname>/img/` it was 301 redirecting to `<vhostname>/img/?_url=img`.

I finally fixed this (I think), by adding in `DirectorySlash off` to my vhost.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you'd want to point DocumentRoot to public/ since app/ should not be accessible via web.

In this example, setting empty path will result in _url == none, otherwise _url will contain whatever path is added.

```
ServerName vhostname
DocumentRoot /vhost/root/dir/public
<Directory "/vhost/root/dir/public">
    AllowOverride none
    Require local
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule ^$ index.php?_url=none [NC,QSA,L]

        # we need to serve static files
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        # pass the path to _url
        RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?_url=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
```

Comment: Turns out it was some kind of browser history issue, my bad. I'll definitely switch my DocumentRoot to the public folder though, should have done that before. I don't have a `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` because I don't want to serve directories or give a 403 forbidden.

Comment: Nevermind that didn't fix it. After changing the DocumentRoot to the public folder it was still happening on the public and app urls, but then clearing the history it stopped happening on them and is happening on the public folder subfolders now.

Comment: Did you restart Apache?

Comment: With -d removed, I do not see browser address bar changed.

Comment: Ya, I restart apache everytime I change the vhosts. If I take out the -d line, clear chrome history by hitting the `Clear Browsing Data` button, then go to `http://<vhostname>/img` (without a trailing /) or any other subdirectory of my DocumentRoot, then the address bar changes to `<vhostname>/js/?_url=js`